# Simulation of long-running Oracle DB query

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jta

What is the simplest (preferably without any new table creation) way of running a database query which takes long time (at least several minutes) in Oracle DB?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider using **DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(300)**, where parameter - number of seconds to wait.

Answer (score 3):

DBMS_LOCK.sleep

(http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/UsefulProceduresAndFunctions9i.php)